# Calling a single function from the YouTube Player API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

I want to use the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) to call a single function that will stop an embedded YT video (loaded dynamically on the page with JS and jQuery) from playing on a button click.

I'm admittedly (very) new to working with APIs for web development and despite reading through several of the other answers (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824070/youtube-api-dynamic-iframe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283871/pause-youtube-video-youtube-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530734/youtube-iframe-api-on-dynamically-created-iframe)), I am still confused as to the necessity of the different JS components.

---

I have a code block that is dynamically appended multiple times to the HTML page, with the YouTube URL changing for each entry based on a separate JSON file. The added code is as follows...

```html
<li>
  <section class="youtube-video">
    <iframe src="'theLoadedURL'?enablejsapi=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1">
    </iframe>
  </section>
</li>
```

... and then I have added the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>` that loads(?) the API...

```html
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

... and finally a simple button for demonstration.

```html
<button> Stop Video </button>
```

---

I was hoping that there would be a way to then simply call the `player.stopVideo();` function from the API and have it affect the already-embedded iFrame on the button click, something like...

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('.youtube-video iframe').stopVideo();
});
```

... but alas, it doesn't seem to be that simple!

---

The documentation and other answers appear to suggest defining various variables and functions for the player, or deal with loading videos manually (rather than dynamically, as in this case); but it seems unnecessarily complex for an element that is already loaded on the page - is there something that I'm missing or an obvious way of simplifying things?

Detailed answers would be much appreciated as I'm still getting to grips with JS in general.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you include the youtube player source code you have so I can see how you have set the player properties please? Thank you.

Comment: is `stopVideo` some sort of jquery thing? if not, `$('.youtube-video iframe')[0].stopVideo();` may work

Comment: Hi @NewToJS , this will perhaps show my lack of understanding but what would this code look like? So far the only code I have written is that that inserts the html `<li>` block containing the iframe, I am struggling with how you set up the player properties and what is necessary to include/define/set-up, etc?

Comment: @Jaromanda X , the `stopVideo()` function comes from the YouTube API documentation, where it is listed as `player.stopVideo();`

Comment: Maybe this example will be of some help [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/agtrkeyh/)

Comment: Thanks @NewToJS , the fiddle was similar to what the documentation showed but I've been playing around with it today and think I've developed a solution to my problem! Just putting together an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from playing around with New's fiddle from the comments, I believe I have found the simplest way of implementing the Youtube Player API, in my situation.

---

Firstly, it requires minor editing the HTML `<li>` code block that, in practice, would be loaded dynamically onto my page:

```
<li>
    <section class="active">
        <iframe id="youtube-video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/y1yFiotx3qk?
        rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"
        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </section>
</li>
```

The main changes come from the addition of a class of `.active` being added to the `<section>` tag to specify the current video targeted by the YouTube Player API. The iframe then has an id of `#youtube-video`. It should be noted that all ids and classes are completely arbitrary.

At the bottom of the HTML's `<body>` I have added the API script...

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

... however, found that it is important that this is placed above all other `<script>` tags in the same location.

---

Following this, I have set up my JS file (with jQuery) as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Creates arbitrary global 'player' variable to be defined later
    var player;

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

        setTimeout(function() { //Using this as seemed to come across occasional bugs in Chrome

            console.log('API Loaded!')

            // Selects first <li> tag iframe contained in a section with the class of '.active'
            var $selectedVideo = $('.active #youtube-video')[0];

            // Uses the previous variable to define the youtube player
            player = new YT.Player($selectedVideo);

        }, 100);

    }

    // Calls the Function
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();

});
```

Finally, also within the `$(document).ready()` function, I am able to bind the relevant YouTube Player API event handlers to the `<button>` HTML element:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    player.stopVideo();
});
```

The intention behind my code is to form part of a slideshow, and thus there should only be one section that has the `.active` class at any one time and this can be used to select different videos on different slides.

---

I've put together an example JSFiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/tnyserpg/31/)** that contains a better UI and more in-depth comments, which may be useful to someone in future.